# Can I use Scala standard library in Java code?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

In particular, I want to use `scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3` in a Java application. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Have you tried it? I see [the scala library is in maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library)

Comment: Nope, I haven't; I could not find it immediately via googling. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Before including the entire scala library (which is huge), you should look out for another dependency which implements the murmur hash algorithm, preferably in Java. Scala code in general is somewhat painful to call from Java.

Comment: @Clashsoft agree. I ended up using Guava's MurMur implementation. Although the difference is not that huge (Guava=2.6mb, Scala=5.5mb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You literally just import the class and use it.

So:

Step 1: include the scala library in your classpath

Step 2: import class and use it.

If you need more examples, [here you go](https://github.com/travisbrown/scala-java-interop).